# PHP Separate line into variables

Tags: php, preg-match

i have text with many lines like this:

```
(item (Index Value) (Name Value)(Name2 Value2)(Name3 Value3) (Speciality (Name-a value-a)  (Name-b value-b))
```

Real example:

```
(item(name 256)(Index 1)(Image "Wea001")(Action 1 1)(class weapon sword)(code 1 1 1 1)(country 2)(level 1)(wear 1)   (limit Knight 1)(range 16)(buy 4)(sell 1)(endurance 4)(specialty(aspeed 700)(Attack 3 10)(hit 15)))
```

Now i want to save them in array $Items[$Index] -*index value is the (Index XX) in the line*-

and in each value new array contain the values in this, for example (using the real line)

```
$Items[1]{
$Name => 256,
$Image => 'Wea001',
$Action=> '1 1',
$class => 'weapon sword',
...etc
}
```

i already saved them in the master array using the explode, but using default values 0,1,2,3,..etc not the Index of the line

```
$items = explode('<br />', $inititemcontent);
for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++){
    echo "$items[$i] <br />";
}
```

PS: the index value never repeated, there can never be 2 lines with the same index
PPS: not usually all the small tags (Name Value) exist, some times all of them, some times only some.

Comment: Why is the data in this format in the first place?  Also, your data doesn't match up with the example.

Comment: Its data file used in game as C++, i wanna use it with PHP so i can only deal with it,
its the same example the master tag is (item ), and into it there are small tags (NameOfTheTag ItsValue), also there are one of the tags called Specialty include smaller tags :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was noticing that the format of the original file was similar to JSON after I wrote the first answer, so I wrote this:

```
    <?php
    $string = '(item(name 256)(Index 1)(Image "Wea001")(Action 1 1)(class weapon sword)(code 1 1 1 1)(country 2)(level 1)(wear 1)   (limit Knight 1)(range 16)(buy 4)(sell 1)(endurance 4)(specialty(aspeed 700)(Attack 3 10)(hit 15)))';



    $patterns = array(
    '!\(!',
    '!\)!',
    '!\{([^\{}]+)\{!',
    '!\},\},\}!',
    '!\},([^}])!',
    '!\{([^ ]+) ([^}]+)\}!',
    '!"!',
    "!'!",
    "!\}(,)?!",
    "!\},$!",
    );
    $replacements = array(
    "{",
    "},",
    "{\"$1':[\n{'",
    "}]}]}",
    "},\n$1",
    "{'$1':'$2'}",
    '',
    '"',
    "}$1\n",
    "}"
    );

    $string = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$string);
    //print $string;
    $items = json_decode($string,true);

    print_r($items);

    ?>
```

Output Source looks like this:

```
Array
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => 256
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Index] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [Image] => Wea001
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [Action] => 1 1
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [class] => weapon sword
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => 1 1 1 1
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [country] => 2
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [level] => 1
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [wear] => 1
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [limit] => Knight 1
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [range] => 16
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [buy] => 4
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [sell] => 1
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [endurance] => 4
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [specialty] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [aspeed] => 700
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Attack] => 3 10
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [hit] => 15
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work? Since there is only one line for the example I didn't have much to go on.

```
<?php
    $string = '(item(name 256)(Index 1)(Image "Wea001")(Action 1 1)(class weapon sword)(code 1 1 1 1)(country 2)(level 1)(wear 1)   (limit Knight 1)(range 16)(buy 4)(sell 1)(endurance 4)(specialty(aspeed 700)(Attack 3 10)(hit 15)))';

    preg_match_all('!\([^()]+\)!s',$string,$parts);

    $items = array();


    foreach($parts as $index=>$temp_array){
        foreach($parts[$index] as $key=>$component){
            $component = preg_replace('![()]!','',$component);
            preg_match_all('!([^ ]+) ([^)]+)!',$component,$component_parts);

            $temp_key = $component_parts[1][0];
            $temp_val = $component_parts[2][0];
            $items[$index][$temp_key]=$temp_val;
        }
    }

    print_r($items);

?>
```

Output looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 256
        [Index] => 1
        [Image] => "Wea001"
        [Action] => 1 1
        [class] => weapon sword
        [code] => 1 1 1 1
        [country] => 2
        [level] => 1
        [wear] => 1
        [limit] => Knight 1
        [range] => 16
        [buy] => 4
        [sell] => 1
        [endurance] => 4
        [aspeed] => 700
        [Attack] => 3 10
        [hit] => 15
    )

)
```

Comment: As a note, the last three are supposed to be nested.

Comment: Well, that makes it harder. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Are they [items] separated by new lines in the code or semicolons?

Comment: new line, i already saved each item in array using:
$item = explode('<br />', $inititemcontent);
now want to make it set in each one the new array in the :
for($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++){ }
and the array arranged by the Index,
for example $items[1][name] = 256

Comment: OKAY , fixed :D, now can i change the normal auto_increase value in the array with the index value?

Comment: Its working as  print_r($item[0]);, but when i use  print_r($item[0][Index]); doesn't work >.<

Comment: You would just use print for that... it's not an array.
print ($item[0]['Index']);